# Get ListView item's details on ItemClick() event

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, onitemclick

I've tried searching around here and on microsoft docs but I can't find a solution to my specific query, as mainly I've seen posts about how to do things on itemclick rather than retrieve data.

I'm currently using an API, which sends a JSON request that I deserialize into 2 partial classes, where I use a foreach loop to add new items to the ListView. You can see the classes here:

```
public partial class GameListObject
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public long GameID { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string GameName { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("release_dates")]
        public ObservableCollection<ReleaseDate> ReleaseDates { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class ReleaseDate
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("human")]
        public string Human { get; set; }
    }
```

And the request, deserialization and adding to the ListView here:

```
//On search box content change
    private async void gamehub_search_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var SearchQuery = gamehub_search.Text;

        try
        {
            // Construct the HttpClient and Uri
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            Uri uri = new Uri("https://api.igdb.com/v4/games");

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Client-ID", App.GlobalClientidIGDB);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + App.GlobalAccessIGDB);
            //Debug.WriteLine("Request Headers: ");

            // Construct the JSON to post
            HttpStringContent content = new HttpStringContent($"search \"{SearchQuery}\"; fields name,release_dates.human;");
            Debug.WriteLine("Request Contents: " + content);

            // Post the JSON and wait for a response
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(
                uri,
                content);

            // Make sure the post succeeded, and write out the response
            httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var httpResponseBody = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine("Request Response: " + httpResponseBody);

            //Deserialise the return output into game id, game name and release date
            List<GameListObject> gamelistobjects = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<GameListObject>>(httpResponseBody);

            ObservableCollection<GameListObject> dataList = new ObservableCollection<GameListObject>(gamelistobjects);
            ObservableCollection<GameListObject> GameList = new ObservableCollection<GameListObject>();

            foreach (var item in dataList)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"id: {item.GameID}");
                Debug.WriteLine($"name: {item.GameName}");

                GameListObject add = new GameListObject() { GameID = item.GameID, GameName = item.GameName };
                GameList.Add(add);

                if (item.ReleaseDates != null)
                {
                    foreach (var date in item.ReleaseDates)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine($"releaseDate: {date.Human}");
                    }
                }
            }
            gamehub_list.ItemsSource = GameList;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

Now I have set an gamehub_list_ItemClick method which runs when an item within the ListView is pressed. **I would like to retrieve the GameID that's present in that item** because I'll need that for another page which the user gets redirected to so that I know what game I must request data for. However, I've tried finding the index of the item and using the member names of the class to retrieve it but I can't seem to get it working.

The ItemClick method currently is:

```
private void gamehub_list_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e) //When an item in List View is pressed
    {
        string clickedItemText = e.ClickedItem.ToString();

        Debug.WriteLine("Click Item text: " + clickedItemText);
    }
```

When I tried to get the index of the item, it always returned as -1 and for the current clickedItemText it returns "Click Item text: ReviewR.GameHubs+GameListObject".

My xaml with the ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="gamehub_list" SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="gamehub_list_ItemClick" Margin="30,140,44,30" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Gray" RequestedTheme="Dark" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding GameID}"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding GameName}"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Click Item text: ReviewR.GameHubs+GameListObject

The problem is `ClickedItem` is object type, if you pass it to string directly, it will return text like you mentioned above.

For this scenario, you need unbox `ClickedItem`.

```
var clickedItem = e.ClickedItem as GameListObject
Debug.WriteLine("Click Item text: " + clickedItem.GameID );
```

Comment: Thank you mate! I understand the mistake now appreciate you explaining it :)